# Grouping based on ROW_Number of each group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I had a requirement that grouping based on row_number of each group. Please view 
 Image

[image: Image - please view this]

Comment: Please add the table data instead of an image on a separate site that can disappear in the future. Also is `row_number` a column?

Comment: What did you try? show us your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries represent *unordered* sets.  So, the distinction between the two groups for 47641 is undefined.

You *can* define a query that will assign a group that has exactly one `fiberid` for each `scname`.  When there are multiples, the assignment is arbitrary.

To do so, you can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       (dense_rank() over (order by scname) - 1 + 
        row_number() over (partition by scname, fiberid order by fiberid)
       ) as grp
from t;
```

If you do have an ordering for the rows then a more stable assignment can be calculated.